# golang: how to explain the type assertion efficiency?

Tags: go

The type assertion would involve call to runtime.assertE2T or runtime.assertE2I (you could see the assembly codes).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type I interface {
    echo()
}

type A struct{}

func (a *A) echo() {}

type testfn func()

func run(f testfn) {
    ts := time.Now()
    f()
    te := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(te.Sub(ts))
}

func testE2T() {
    var i interface{} = new(A)
    for a := 0; a < 500000000; a++ {
        _ = i.(*A)
    }
}

func testE2I() {
    var i interface{} = new(A)
    for a := 0; a < 500000000; a++ {
        _ = i.(I)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("testE2I:")
    run(testE2I)
    fmt.Println("testE2T:")
    run(testE2T)
}
```

result:

```
testE2I:
11.065225934s
testE2T:
5.720773381s
```

It seems that the type assertion is slower than the pointer cast in C? How to explain it?

And it's strange that when I use gccgo to run the same program, it would cause out-of-memory error. Does the gccgo has some limitation in gc?

Comment: For a start, your approach at optimisation is completely backwards and wrong, hence a waste of time. Write a program that solves an actual real-world problem (*seeing which is fastest* doesn't count as an actual real-world problem). Then *use a profiler* to determine where the most significant bottlenecks are, and target them for optimisation. That way, you won't be guessing and possibly getting it wrong; when you get it wrong, you potentially push the more significant bottlenecks outside of your window of time (or possibly even computer resources).

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour not all things. we may choose programming language based on some points, like interface casting performance.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour, this question is abstracted from the real-world project, where the type assertion comes from the variant type access and cost many CPU time from profiling, especially compared to the C pointer cast version. The project itself is not possible to be shared with public domain. Every language has some points which are worth handling them carefully, especially for newbies. If you have some concrete points about the question, please help directly; if not, since not everyone here is guru, so please take it easy yourself. Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @kingluo I am helping... See my comment above for help!

Comment: By the way, please see the [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) package for the Go standard way of writing and running benchmarks.

Comment: ^^ E.g., put [this](https://play.golang.org/p/zSMP9UtAF5.go) into a `*_test.go` file and run something like `go test -bench=.` to get a standard Go benchmark result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't quite figure out what's your *main* question, but I'll try to answer the ones you asked as best as I can.

> It seems that the type assertion is slower than the pointer cast in C?

Yes, it is. Type assertions need to be safe at runtime, thus there is a number of [checks](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.4.2/src/runtime/iface.go#L219) they need to perform. It's even worse with interface-to-interface assertion, because you also need to ensure that the type implements the interface.

With that said, they can definitely perform better. In fact, here is comparison of your benchmark results on Go 1.4.2. vs latest dev version of Go 1.5:

- Go 1.4.2: `testE2I: 10.014922955s, testE2T: 4.465621814s`
- Go 1.5 dev: `testE2I: 7.201485053s, testE2T: 287.08346ms`

It's more than ten times faster now, and Go 1.6's new SSA backend might bring even better optimisations.

> And it's strange that when I use gccgo to run the same program, it would cause out-of-memory error. Does the gccgo has some limitation in gc?

My guess it that it's gccgo's lack of escape analysis, but I may be wrong. I was actually able to run the benchmark with gccgo on my machine, but it consumed about 9 GB of RAM, which is everything but normal. I'm pretty sure that [filing an issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/new) about that wouldn't hurt. Anyway, here are the results with `-O3`:

- gccgo: `testE2I: 30.405681s, testE2T: 1.734307s`

Faster on the concrete type, but much slower with interface-to-interface assertion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's helpful.